# Instantiate objects having a property of the object type itself

Tags: c#, oop

Is there a better way of instantiating an object say for example has the same type as a property in it. As in the example below, I have an Employee class containing property Manager of type Employee,

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee Manager { get; set; }


}
```

if instantiated

```
Employee n1 = new Employee{ 
   Name="emp1", 
   Manager = new Employee(){
      Name="mgr1", 
      Manager= new Employee(){ ...
```

The instantiation would go on till we reach the top level now in case the organization heirarchy is huge (please assume may be 500 levels) is there a better way to instantiate.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please add a code example.

Comment: Manager is not nested class of Employee. What do you want to do now?

Comment: I was reffering to the above case sorry guess its not a nested class by definition. But when I try to instantiate an employee and go up to the CEO how do I instantiate? Sorry I havent used SO a lot. Please correct me if i am wrong in anyway.

Comment: well I guess at some point there will be no *bigger* Manager (guess  `Manager = null` in this case - which I kindof like ;) )

Comment: well thaats what i thought but wouldnt the code be huge if there is a big hierarchy unless you define the manager as null ;)

Comment: Instantiate all your Employee objects (perhaps keep a List of them). Set the Manager of each Employee to the correct Employee object. Task done. If you want to maintain a requirement that all employees must ultimately be managed by a single Employee who is the CEO, then instead of having an `Employee Manager` property, you might consider having a `List<Employee> Subordinates` property. Then your CEO variable points to an Employee from which all subordinates, and their subordinates, must descend. Someone with no subordinates has the list set to an empty list (probably better than null).

Answer (score 1):

Well why not declarative:

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Employee Manager { get; set; }

   public static Employee CreateBigBoss(string name) // insert a enterprisey name here
   {
       return new Employee { Name = name, Manager = null };
   }

   public Employee CreateSubordinate(string name)
   {
       return new Employee { Name = name, Manager = this };
   }
}
```

use it like this:

```
var burns = Employee.CreateBigBoss("Mr Burns");
var smithers = burns.CreateSubordinate("Mr Smithers");
```

Comment: Yeah, this is better, I deleted my answer.

Comment: yes better. thank you. But is this the only way? Is there some language feature that I dont know of?

Comment: no this is not the only way (of course) - there are lot's of ways - and I cannot tell if you are missing some lang. feature here - it's a matter of taste and programming style

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes are classes **declared** inside the declaration of another class.

What you are describing is nested instances and you did it fine.

This is a nested class:

```
class MyOuterClass {
    string outerClassName { get; set; }

    class MyInnerClass {
        string innerClassName { get; set; }
    }

    MyInnerClass myInnerClass = new MyInnerClass() {
        innerClassName = "inner";
    }
}
```

Most situations don't call for an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this in main or whetever you use it.
Employee n1 = new Employee();
Employee manager = new Employee();
manager.IsCEO = true;
manager.Name = "Manager Name";

n1.Name = "John";
n1.Manager = manager;


class Employee
{
    private Employee _manager = new Employee();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsCEO{ get; set;}

    public Employee Manager 
    { 
       get
       {
            if(IsCEO)
               return null;
            else
               return _manager;
       } 
       set
       {
            if(!IsCEO)
               _manager=value;
       }
    }   

}
```

Something like this ?

Comment: In real life (as well as in the original design) you can *be* a manager *and have* a manager at the same time.

Comment: @nvoigt are you happy now ? After changing the IsManager to IsCEO ? Also in real life I will never ever write something like this. The whole class have bad structure.

Comment: So recommend a better structure. Also, what on earth is `get {} else` ? A strange construct, there. :)

Comment: @ErikE it is set. It is typo, sorry about that.